# In Sublime expand selection across open files or project

Tags: sublimetext3, selection, expand

What I wish to do: Select an occurrence of a word/variable in a file (python) and then expand the selection across all open files or within the project (so that I can replace the word/variable with something else).

What I know: With ctrl+d I can go to the next occurrence and with alt+F3 I can expand the selection in the *current* file. I know I can use search and replace, but it is not very intuitive. So I'm looking for a variant of alt+F3 with the addition that text is selected over all open files or within the project.

Any plugin? possible to customize settings or keybindings?

Comment: There's no way to do this out of the box, so some external plugin would be needed although I don't know of any offhand. Realistically if you want to perform a replace across multiple files, `Find in Files` is the tool for the job although you can't review the changes before they're made (nor can you if you use `Alt+F3`, though).

Comment: thanks for clarifying @OdatNurd